# Connect to web-service

Tags: python

I have some PHP code, similar to that shown below, which makes a connection and gets a response (from a web-service).

How would I do something similar in Python?

```
$cObj = curl_init();.
curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_URL,$this->urlws.'/trlink/link1/trlink');
curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());

curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"XMLString=".$xml);

$this->xml_response = curl_exec($cObj);.
```

Comment: Please [ask the question in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). Not in Spanish. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this is translated to French, but not Spanish. Maybe you can deduce enough though: http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try SUDS https://fedorahosted.org/suds/